# Operation not permitted when creating tablespace

Tags: postgresql

im trying to create a tablespace and keep getting the same error

```
pablo@MisCompras-dev:~$ psql -d postgres -U pablo
psql (11.2 (Ubuntu 11.2-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# create tablespace miscompras_space owner pablo location '/home/pablo/postgres';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/home/pablo/postgres": Operation not permitted
```

i set the permissions of /home, /home/pablo, and /home/pablo/postgres to 777 and got the same error when creating a tablespace.

i also added pablo to the access control list of those three directories with the following command:

```
setfacl -m pablo:rwx [directory]
```

when i type:

```
getfacl [directory]
```

user:pablo:rwx appears for all 3. what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablespace directory must be owned by postgres, so

```
chown postgres:postgres /home/pablo/postgres
```

Then try again running:

```
postgres=# create tablespace miscompras_space owner pablo location '/home/pablo/postgres';
```

Good luck

Comment: thank you! you have no idea how much time i spent on this

Comment: It is giving the following >> chown: postgres: illegal group name; how do i resolve this.